# Is there an alternative private messsage module that integrates with Views?

Tags: privatemsg, 7

As far as I can tell it's the only real solution on the block. But it has major drawbacks that make it unusable for most sites. Mainly its not built with views, therefore easy customization is out of the question unless I change the code.

Are there any alternatives, paid or free, that beat [privatemsg](https://www.drupal.org/project/privatemsg) and integrate with [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views)?

Answer (score 1):

You can also consider theming Private Message.  Private Message is an extremely powerful module that offers a much higher degree of customization than some sites may need (messages can be sent to users + roles at the same time, etc.)

For my site, I added several tweaks to actually limit/reduce Private Message's functionality (users can only have one thread per user, users can only message one user at a time, users cannot send more than three messages in a row to the same user, etc.)

Messaging systems are pretty complex so I found it easier to start with the huge number of options Private Message provides and then reduce them.

You could also [help work on privatemsg views integration](https://www.drupal.org/node/1573000), though this is a huge project.

Comment: what do you mean by theming in this case? do you mean digging into the modules code and tearing it apart? if so, is it possible for you to share a bit of the code you changed for example "users can only have one thread per user" When i get asked to add user picture its frustrating because in views this could be done in seconds.

Comment: By theming, I mean customizing `privatemsg.theme.inc` in my theme; this allows me, for example, to use my own custom user picture (a field in the user profile) instead of the default Drupal user picture, which my site does not allow.  Code for "maintain a single thread between two users" and other examples can be found in the Privatemsg documentation: https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/privatemsg.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [message private](https://www.drupal.org/project/message_private) module. It has the ability of integration with Views module. It's a little new so may lack some features. If you want to stick with privatemsg then there is a patch [here](https://drupal.org/node/1573000) which can integrate it with Views.

I hope this helps.

Comment: I tried this module, and it does use views so theming is easy, but the overall structure and setup is no good. It's way worse than Privatemsg.

Comment: like I said the module did views integration but not that much useful as Privatemsg. I would suggest go for the patch I suggested and do some work on views integrations